# How do I make the ends shorter?

Tags: modeling, faces

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaaCelb6m0c&t=204), up to the part where I had to make the bottom end shorter, but the faces keep overlapping when I'm trying to shorten them. Am I doing something wrong or is that how it's supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you did before that, but in your screenshot it looks like the side faces you are trying to shorten are either doubled somehow (then they stay in place while the others move) or before moving them up you've made a loop cut so they are cut in half and your moving the lower part up past the upper part. In both cases you did something wrong and it's not how it's supposed to be. I would suggest you follow the tutorial more carefully, sorry.

Comment: Or add some more details to your post: what the current situation is, what you want to change, and what approach does not work.

Comment: tysm for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

your faces may keep overlapping if you're moving geometry by extruding, E to extrude when you want to CREATE new geometry but use G (optional: and then an axis (x,y,z)) to only move the geometry you currently have (and have selcted).

I hope you found this helpful :) and good luck on your project!

Blender can be confusing at first but it's well worth the struggle, don't give up!